# Visual Studio Item Wizard - Reference SignalR assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, wizard

I have a wizard that creates a particular item for a Visual Studio project.
The wizard opens a Win Form that needs to connect to a SignalR Server to retrieve some data.
The problem is that, when I add a new Item in a VS project and the Wizard is loaded, it can't find the reference for SignalR assembly, returning this message: Unable to load file or assembly Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client ...

The question is: how can I reference external assembly in a VS Wizard project?

Answer (score 0):

If you have added it through NuGet this will probably help: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/packages-in-visual-studio-templates

Answer (score 0):

Solved - I need to use the external dll as an embedded resource. I followed this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528178/Load-DLL-From-Embedded-Resource?msg=4781811#xx4781811xx